# Replace comma in a string, BUT only at a specific position in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, replace

I am reading a csv file in VB.net and saving the line to a SQL database. At a later point in my code, the SQL line is retrived in the application, and the Split function is used to get 'field' values. The Split is done taking comma as the seperator.

The application processes many other files (including excel), and the split function is used for all of them.

The problem I am now facing is that one of the csv files I read, has a field value that starts with " followed by multiple values seperated by a comma and ends with another ". The normal reading of the csv file results in each of those single field values is taken to be a seperate value. Hope I am making sense?

An example line is:

```
Elker,MissB,"Bus, Taxi, Train, Ferry, Parking, Toll",800253
```

where there should only be separated to 4 columns, they get separated to 9 columns instead.

What I want to do is replaced the commas after 'Bus' and until 'Toll' with a '?' instead.

I have tried using `Replace`, including the overloaded one with starting position, but it ends up replacing ALL the commas in the line with '?'

Attempt 1:

```
If vstrLine(intStartPos) = "," Then
    strRetVal = Replace(vstrLine(intStartPos), ",", "?")
end if
```

where `vstrLine` is `Elker,MissB,"Bus, Taxi, Train, Ferry, Parking, Toll",800253`
and `intStartPos` is the first instance of a comma after the "

It returns only the '?' and not the string with 1 comma replaced by '?'

Attempt 2:

```
If vstrLine(intStartPos) = "," Then
    strRetVal = Replace(vstrLine, ",", "?", intStartPos)
end if
```

It returns a string with all commas replaced with '?'

Comment: Use http://www.filehelpers.com/default.html. It's free and handles exactly this. There are plenty of examples on SO! Also, quotes in CSV are a way of indicating text, and FileHelpers deals with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression that matches either a quoted value or a value containing no comma.

Example:

```
Dim input As String = "Elker,MissB,""Bus, Taxi, Train, Ferry, Parking, Toll"",800253"
Dim values As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, "("".*""|[^,]+)")

For Each value As Match In values
  Console.WriteLine(value.Value)
Next
```

Output:

```
Elker
MissB
"Bus, Taxi, Train, Ferry, Parking, Toll"
800253
```

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? Unless you are wanting to do something very much custom, use a already made CSV reader. I would recommend [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use VB's built in TextFieldParser class.  It can handle reading a csv file and will properly deal with commas in a field.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx